# fill missing gap in table structure, using cv2 python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am trying to extract coordinates for each cell from a tabular image in grayscale using [cv2.findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)

But I'm not able to get exact tables due to gaps in between lines. I tried with [cv2.dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) followed by [cv2.erode](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) with both horizontal and vertical kernels of size (1, 5) and (5, 1) but before filling the gaps lines become thick enough to fill the cell.

**Please look at the image to get the idea.**
[image: Updated image]

Comment: I couldnt understand the exact problem. Why ```erode``` and ```dilate``` and what for?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I have updated the image have a look, please.

Comment: Please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859750/how-to-connect-broken-lines-in-a-binary-image-using-python-opencv) solves your problem.

Comment: You can detct the joints first by using a similar approach like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633334/how-to-detect-corner-joints-that-connect-elements-on-images). Then you can complete those uncompleted lines by adding pixels to their end until joints

Comment: Btw this seems a goog problem, you can make this question also be better by editing

Comment: To connect broken lines/edges based on contour extremities have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811385/connecting-disjointed-lines-or-edges-in-binary-images/71816288#71816288