# Join lines to create closed contours using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have the following image:
[image]

And I would like to join all of these "green" linear pixels to create a bounding box contour - is this something that is possible with opencv?

Thanks

Comment: A closing operator (used multiple times) will possibly do the trick. It will affect other areas as well, so it might not be what you want. I don't know OpenCV well, but I guess it can do this.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: I tried this already Stefan and didn't seem to work for me unfortunately. Thanks

Comment: Another approach is using the Hough transform to detect the line(s). Here you'll get the intercept and slope of the detected line.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859750/how-to-connect-broken-lines-in-a-binary-image-using-python-opencv) can help?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk that suggestion is a closing operation as we have discussed above

Comment: @user1655130 I've posted a simple approach

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the given image and used the following as input:

**Input image**

[image]

Performing threshold and finding contours:

```
th = cv2.threshold(img, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cnts = cv2.findContours(th , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
```

Now the fun part!

- For each contour, find the extreme points. These are the **top-most**, **bottom-most**, **right-most** and **left-most** points of the contour.
- Compare the distance between every extreme point of a contour with those of every other contour
- Draw a line between points with the least Euclidean distance.

**Code:**

```
for i in range(len(cnts)):
    min_dist = max(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])
    cl = []
    
    ci = cnts[i]
    ci_left = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
    ci_right = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
    ci_top = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
    ci_bottom = tuple(ci[ci[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
    ci_list = [ci_bottom, ci_left, ci_right, ci_top]
    
    for j in range(i + 1, len(cnts)):
        cj = cnts[j]
        cj_left = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        cj_right = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
        cj_top = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        cj_bottom = tuple(cj[cj[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
        cj_list = [cj_bottom, cj_left, cj_right, cj_top]
        
        for pt1 in ci_list:
            for pt2 in cj_list:
                dist = int(np.linalg.norm(np.array(pt1) - np.array(pt2)))     #dist = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
                if dist < min_dist:
                    min_dist = dist             
                    cl = []
                    cl.append([pt1, pt2, min_dist])
    if len(cl) > 0:
        cv2.line(img1, cl[0][0], cl[0][1], (255, 255, 255), thickness = 5)
```

**Output image:**

[image]