# How to connect broken lines that cannot be connected by erosion and dilation?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image like this that has multiple stoppers and some of the lines are broken. To connect this broken line, I used a morphological operation like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sample.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(im, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((10,10),np.uint8))
```

But this didn't connect my broken lines. How can I connect the lines without affecting the other lines?

**img**

A line break is a break between two small lines in the center of the image. Only the discontinuous part does not have rounded ends.

[image]

**applied morphological operation**

[image: applied morphological operation]

Comment: You likely want to detect the lines (maybe Hough?) and find some logic that will determine whether to connect the lines or not. You could also make a skeleton, detect end points, then try to figure out which end points to join. A simple closing is never going to give you good results here.

Comment: To connect curved, broken lines/edges based on contour extremities have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811385/connecting-disjointed-lines-or-edges-in-binary-images/71816288#71816288

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 1. You can use `createFastLineDetector` for detecting each line.

---

- 2. Calculate the slope of the current and neighboring lines.

---

- 3. If the slope of current and neighboring lines are the same draw line.

---

***Initializing Line Detector***

---

We will be using `ximgproc` library for detecting lines.

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("lines.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
d = cv2.ximgproc.createFastLineDetector()
lines = d.detect(gray)
```

- The `lines` variable returns similar values like `[[14.82, 78.90, 90.89, 120.78]]` where `x1=14.82`, `y1=78.90`, `x2=90.89`, `y2=120.78` respectively.

***Calculating Slope***

---

- The slope of a line is calculated with the formula: m = (`y2` - `y1`) / (`x2` - `x1`)
- For a given line object, get the coordinates and return the slope.
- ```py
  def calculate_slope(line_object):
      x_point1 = line_object[0]
      y_point1 = line_object[1]
      x_point2 = line_object[2]
      y_point2 = line_object[3]

      m = abs((y_point2 - y_point1) / (x_point2 - x_point1))
      m = float("{:.2f}".format(m))
      return m
  ```

***Comparing Slopes***

---

- 1. Check the equality of the lines. if the points are equal, that means they are the same line.

  - ```py
    for current_line in lines:
         current_slope = calculate_slope(current_line[0])

         for neighbor_line in lines:
             current_x1 = int(current_line[0][0])
             current_y1 = int(current_line[0][1])
             current_x2 = int(current_line[0][2])
             current_y2 = int(current_line[0][3])

             compare_lines = current_line == neighbor_line[0]
             equal_arrays = compare_lines.all()
    ```
- 2. If the lines are not equal, calculate the neighbor's line slope.

     ```py
     if not equal_arrays:
         neighbor_slope = calculate_slope(neighbor_line[0])
     ```
- 3. If slopes are equal, draw the line. From `neighbor` to `current` and `current` to `neighbor`.

     ```py
     if abs(current_slope - neighbor_slope) < 1e-3:
         neighbor_x1 = int(neighbor_line[0][0])
         neighbor_y1 = int(neighbor_line[0][1])
         neighbor_x2 = int(neighbor_line[0][2])
         neighbor_y2 = int(neighbor_line[0][3])

         cv2.line(img,
                  pt1=(neighbor_x1, neighbor_y1),
                  pt2=(current_x2, current_y2),
                  color=(255, 255, 255),
                  thickness=3)
         cv2.line(img,
                  pt1=(current_x1, current_y1),
                  pt2=(neighbor_x2, neighbor_y2),
                  color=(255, 255, 255),
                  thickness=3)
     ```

Result

---

[image]

***Possible Question*** But why couldn't you connect the following parts?

[image]

***Answer***

Well, the red dotted line slopes are not equal. Therefore I couldn't connect them.

***Possible Question*** Why didn't you use `dilate` and `erode` methods? as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859750/how-to-connect-broken-lines-in-a-binary-image-using-python-opencv)

***Answer***

I tried, but the result is not satisfactory.

Comment: Nice answer! Only the part where you do `current_slope == neighbor_slope` makes me worry. I've learned to never, ever, do an equality comparison with floating-point numbers. Add a small tolerance to the comparison: `abs(current_slope - neighbor_slope) < 1e-3` (or similar).

Comment: This is the first time, I have a compliment from my senior. Thanks for evaluating my answer. I've added the change as you suggested. I appreciate your comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, that's a very good idea! Thank you for your reference.